# React Time Picker (rc-time-picker)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

in my project I used Primereact calendar component to use the timn picker.
Here is the sample code

```
 import { Calendar } from 'primereact/components/calendar/Calendar';
 <Calendar showTime={true}
 hourFormat={12}
 readOnlyInput={true}
 showSeconds={true}
 className="timeInput"
 value={this.props.processStartTime} 
 timeOnly="true" 
 onChange={this.props.onChangeStartTime} 
 placeholder='Select Process Start Time'>
 </Calendar>
```

And for onChange i used  this

```
const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
processStartTime: makeSelectProcessStartTime(),
});

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
 onChangeStartTime: (evt) => dispatch(setProcessStartTime(evt.value)),
};
}
```

And it works. But i want to do the same thing in rc-time-picker (http://react-component.github.io/time-picker/) And i followed the same method for an example like this

```
 value={this.state.value}
 onChange={this.props.onChangeStartTime}
```

But it doesn't change the value, how can I make it happens?

Comment: Do `onChangeStartTime: (evt) => console.log(evt)` first and see what you're given. I suspect it's just a value passed, not an event object.

Comment: Yes, the value has passed only

Comment: So, the problem solved?

Comment: i am trying, thank you

Comment: It is working now, i messed up with their value  and defaultValue .